# Como conseguir um efeito slideToggle com jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Neste [link](http://caramori.axitech.com.br), eu tenho umas tarjas vermelhas em especialidade. Gostaria de perguntar qual efeito eu vou usar para que uma `div` substitua o conteúdo das tarjas individualmente com um efeito tipo `slideToggle` da esquerda para a direita. Como começar este *script* em jQuery?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a pergunta. Mas, você pode usar  `transitions` no CSS e `background-position`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comece com alguma coisa tipo isso:

**jquery:**

```
$('.disparador').click(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        width: ($(this).width() == 200 ? 100 : 200)
    });
    $(this).siblings('.painel').animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='painel'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class='disparador'></div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
    <div class='painel'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class='disparador'></div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
    <div class='painel'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class='disparador'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width:200px;
    height: 350px;
    float: left;
}
.painel {
    display:none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 350px;
    overflow: auto;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
}
.disparador {
    width: 200px;
    min-width: 50%;
    height: 350px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    right:0;
    background-color: red;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/jd3ga07f/)

Comment: `$('#widget_sp_image-2, #widget_sp_image-3, #widget_sp_image-4').click(function (e) {` ... tenho 3 ids diferentes ... como aplicaria o painel `$('.painel').animate({width: "toggle"}, 750);` para a sua id especifica?

Comment: Essa é a magia do jquery, crie um mecanismo para apontar ao elemento desejado, usando `data- ` ou outro parâmetro qualquer...

Comment: @marcosvinicius Editei a resposta, agora esta referenciando ao elemento clicado e seu painel. veja funcionando no jsfiddle...

Comment: talvez seja necessário concatenar uma string "px" por causa da unidade de medida, as vezes funciona sem, mas seria uma boa prática colocar

Comment: @leandro17br de acordo com o manual todo valor numérico será tratado como pixels, então acho que não tem necessidade de complicar...

Comment: Consegui fazer um efeito. Muitas das vezes eu tenho dificuldade para fazer a volta do script, tipo ... ele VAI mas como que ele VOLTA? Não sei se entendem, alguma coisa relacionada com o inverso do que acabou de ser feito. Acho que isso é lógica de programação, não?

Comment: @marcosvinicius Para fazer e desfazer, prefira usar o toggle quando disponível, ele sempre inverte a ação automaticamente, ou seja se esta oculto ele mostra, se esta visível ele oculta. Quando o que você quer fazer não disponibiliza uma opção toggle, é preciso verificar a situação atual e aplicar o inverso, como no meu ex. Quero alternar a largura do disparador entre 200 e 100, veja que coloquei um if largura == 200 retorna 100 se não retorna 200